# jWYSIWYG set font color button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wysiwyg, jwysiwyg

I am using `jQuery` WYSIWYG (https://github.com/akzhan/jwysiwyg)

I realize that `jwysiwyg` now includes a color pallete that allows you to color text. But, what I want to do, is to have a custom button OUTSIDE of the editor that applies the color.

**Is there a way to trigger the setting of the font color and pass in a color value?**

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go with "Maybe".

Here's what the [colorpicker](https://github.com/akzhan/jwysiwyg/blob/master/controls/wysiwyg.colorpicker.js) does when you click submit.

```
var color = $('input[name="color"]', dialog.data).val();
self.color.fore.prev = color;
self.addColorToPalette("fore", color);

if ($.browser.msie) {
    Wysiwyg.ui.returnRange();
}

Wysiwyg.editorDoc.execCommand('ForeColor', false, color);
$.modal.close();
return false;
```

Most of that is only useful to the colorpicker, but there's one line that appears to actually set the color in the plugin:

```
Wysiwyg.editorDoc.execCommand('ForeColor', false, color);
```

If the `Wysiwyg` object is in scope for you, you should be able to call this directly with your own colors.  The `color` variable is just a string in the "#rrggbb" format.

Comment: `Wysiwyg` is an object within the plugin that is not exposed externally.  It looks like you'll have to add your own custom method to the plugin that calls the execCommand for you.